# PHP to HTML (Input Textfield / IMG Upload)

Tags: php, html, input, upload

I'm looking to create a script that allows for the ability to update two seperate variables (img and textfield) in a coordinating html page.

I want the user to upload an image, then input a google docs link into a textfield. After they submit both of those variables then the html gets updated/replaced with the new image/link.

Any insight on what the most efficient way to do this/get started would be greatly appreciated! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started on the image upload http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
The rest you should look at tutorials on MySQL/PHP what you are asking to do is very simple to accomplish and with a few hours of studying you can get this done.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yamaha. if you have any specific suggestions where to start with the other task I'd greatly appreciate it. Will both variables need to be sent/received to and from a database? Is there anything more specific I could search for aside from general introduction to PHP/MYSQL to get a more direct solution? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again managed to teach myself a bit of a new knowledge. Here was more specifically what I was looking for. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp